# Is there any way to create a redirect for a DMARC record?

Tags: dns, dmarc

We have SPF on approx 30 domains configured with a redirect like this:

```
v=spf1 redirect=_spf.example.com
```

This simplifies management since changes now only need to happen in one place to affect all of our domains which share the same policy.

Is there anything like this for DMARC? It would be nice to avoid having to create and maintain so many records which will inevitably be identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DMARC` record is in fact a DNS `TXT` record on name `_dmarc` at apex of zone.

As such, you can completely use a CNAME there:

```
_dmarc.client1.example. CNAME _dmarc_for_clients.provider.example.
_dmarc.client2.example. CNAME _dmarc_for_clients.provider.example.
_dmarc.client3.example. CNAME _dmarc_for_clients.provider.example.
_dmarc.client42.example. CNAME _dmarc_for_clients.provider.example.
_dmarc_for_clients.provider.example. TXT "v=DMARC1; p=none"
```

(better not to use `_dmarc` for this need in the `provider.example.` zone as you might/need want, to setup DMARC as well for the name `provider.example` and the content could be completely different than the one needed for "clients" DMARC).

The same trick is used for DKIM records, but can not be used for `SPF` records which are in fact `TXT` records but at apex, and you can't have a `CNAME` record at apex (which is why basically you have `redirect=` inside the SPF pseudo record).

Comment: that's awesome.  in my case `provider.example.` does indeed have an identical record as all of the clients so am I correct in understanding that I just need to do `_dmarc.client1.example. CNAME _dmarc.provider.example.`?  I guess I'll need Dmarc External Validation records for each client domain as well?

Comment: You can use any existing `TXT` record as destination, so `_dmarc` is fine as well if the content is right for your usecase. Note that the above is not specific to DMARC records, `CNAME` is a standard DNS feature you can use for almost anything (you can't for apex).

Comment: DMARC External Validation records are again `TXT` records but you wouldn't get a lot by using CNAME here. Like with `_dmarc_for_clients.provider.example. TXT "v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:a-reports@provider.example; ruf=mailto:f-reports@provider.example"` you need a record of `example.com._report._dmarc.provider.example. TXT "v=DMARC1"` for each client zone (`example.com`). So just have multiple of those `TXT` records, they are all in `provider.example` zone, not in clients zones.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick - that's pretty much what I figured but I really appreciate you verifying it.